# Como detectar el click derecho encima de un JButton en java

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos

He estado buscando la manera pero todas me tiran un error, me gustaría que me ayuden en esto. Estoy haciendo un buscaminas y me falta que cuando le de click derecho me salga una bandera de precaución.

```
JButton boton = new JButton();
```

Comment: El click derecho adopta a veces un comportamiento ambiguo en ciertos sistemas operativos. Te recomiendo que leas este hilo (en inglés): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4525802/5587982 Si usas Swing, para evitar esta ambigüedad lo tendrás muy fácil con esto: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isLeftMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)

Comment: @Awes0meM4n si ya no lo puedes editar, escríbelo de nuevo mejor, así queda menos confuso que corregido por comentario.

Comment: Tienes que hacerte un listener para que el MouseEvent te pueda decir qué botón se ha pulsado: new MouseAdapter() {@Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {if (e.getButton() == e.BUTTON3)...} Prueba a implementarlo y pega el código aquí si tienes algún problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo agregando un `ActionListener` y comprobar los modificadores:

```
    boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if ((e.getModifiers() & 4) !=0){
                 // boton derecho
            }
        }
    });
```

Boton izquierda sería `getModifiers() & 16` y el boton mediano `getModifiers() & 8`.

Alternativamente podrías usar un `MouseListener`:

```
    MouseListener mouseListener= new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getButton());
            // MouseEvent.BUTTON3 es el boton derecho
        }
    };
    boton.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Si usas `onMousePressed` y `onMouseReleased` puedes mostrar tu información solamente mientras el botón esta presionado.

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado de la segunda manera que publicaste, en el mouseClicked{if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){}

Comment: ¡Bueno! He editado tu pregunta un poco para dejar el contexto más claro, pero tuve que adivinar en que componente necesitas el segundo botón. Si quieres, podrías compartir un poco más de tu código en vez de que yo adiviné. Si haces eso, yo arreglo mi respuesta correspondiente después.

Answer (score 0):

Explicado de otra forma, solamente debes crear el evento mauseclicked del botón que necesitas y con una función condicional obtener que botón del ratón se esta presionando por ejemplo:

private void ClickaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
    {

```
    if(evt.getButton() == 3)  //3 es para click derecho pero puedes captar hasta 5
                              //botones del mause

    {
       System.out.println("Se presiono el click derecho");
    }

}
```