# Agregar actionListener a JButton dinamicamente

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo este código, el cual me genera una ventana con un botón.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PruebasGraficas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame Ventana1 = new JFrame();

        Ventana1.setTitle("VENTANA 1");
        Ventana1.setSize(300, 300);
        Ventana1.setLocation(500, 300);
        Ventana1.setVisible(true);
        JButton boton1 = new JButton();
        boton1.setText("EXECUTE");
        boton1.setVisible(true);
        Ventana1.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Ventana1.add(boton1);

    }

}
```

Quisiera saber que forma seria mas correcta para agregar una accion al boton de manera dinamica.

En este caso, que al apretar sobre el boton, este ejecute una accion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No agregues imagenes

Comment: Agrega tu codigo, asi sera mas facil reproducir el error

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como detectar el click derecho encima de un JButton en java](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53254/como-detectar-el-click-derecho-encima-de-un-jbutton-en-java)

Answer (score 1):

**Podrias hacer algo como esto:**

```
package Interfaz;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PruebasGraficas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame Ventana1 = new JFrame();

        Ventana1.setTitle("VENTANA 1");
        Ventana1.setSize(300, 300);
        Ventana1.setLocation(500, 300);
        Ventana1.setVisible(true);

        JButton boton1 = new JButton();
        boton1.setText("EXECUTE");
        boton1.setVisible(true);


        /* Asignamos una Accion al JButton */
        boton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saludos StackOverflow!");
            }

        });

        Ventana1.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Ventana1.add(boton1);
        Ventana1.revalidate();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas un JButton listener (addActionListener), con esto se define qué se debe hacer cuando el usuario realiza una determinada acción.

Ejemplo:

```
JButton btnEjemplo = new JButton("Clic aqui");
        btnEjemplo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // aquí el código que quieres ejecutar cuando el botón sea presionado
                System.out.println("Hellow World!");
            }
        });
        btnEjemplo.setBounds(158, 109, 97, 25);
```

Todo lo que escribas dentro, será ejecutado inmediatamente al hacer clic al botón.